# Find segment x on the secant circles below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, planar-graphs

In the figure determine $'x'$ , knowing that $PM=MQ=4$ and $O$ and $O'$ are centers.(S:$x=4$)

[image]

I try:

$\triangle OQH \sim \triangle OAP \implies \dfrac{HO}{OP} = \dfrac{HQ}{AP} = \dfrac{8+OP}{AO}$

$\triangle (OQH-PA): 8.AO.NH = OP.NQ.AH$

$\triangle PQN \sim \triangle HAN: \dfrac{HN}{PN}=\dfrac{AN}{QN}=\dfrac{AH}{PQ}$

$\triangle HAN \sim \triangle QHO: \dfrac{HN}{OH}=\dfrac{AN}{8+OP}=\dfrac{AH}{QH}$

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Draw the triangle $\triangle OPD$ and $\triangle OLP$

By simple angle chasing you can find out the blue angles are equal.

Now look at $\triangle QLO$ and $/triangle GLO$ they are similar.

With this information, you can get the following relationship

$\frac{r-4}{OL}=\frac{r+4}{OL}$

$(OL)^2=(r+4).(r-4)$

Look at $\triangle QLN$ as $\angle QLN=90^o$

$r^2=x^2+(OL)^2$ as $(OL)^2=(r+4).(r-4)$

Then finally u get,

$r^2=x^2+(r+4).(r-4)$

$r^2=x^2+r^2-4^2$

AT THE END

$\boxed{x=4}$

Thank you @peta arantes for giving us a great problem to solve!

Comment: It is I who appreciate the help

Comment: Who is $G$? $\angle QLN = 90^o$  It woul be $\angle OLN$ . It woulde be $\triangle QLO \sim\triangle LOP$

Comment: t is I who thank you for your help

Comment: The one you are referring to G is my 4. My teachers always scold me for bad handwriting sorry :)